# Case statement should not return null values

Tags: oracle

I have a case statement, which returns null values in a column whereas I dont want the null values when executing the case statement.

```
SELECT ABC
(
CASE 
 WHEN 
 condition
 THEN 1
 WHEN
condition2
 THEN 2 
 END
 ) AS column_name FROM tablename;
```

Column_name returns null values as well

So I changed the query to

```
SELECT ABC
(
CASE 
 WHEN 
 condition
 THEN 1
 WHEN
condition2
 THEN 2 
 else 3
 END
 ) AS column_name FROM tablename where column_name <>3;
```

I get an error 'invalid identifier'.

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: What is ABC ? A function you created?

Comment: Then you are missing a comma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a comma after `ABC` (assuming that `ABC` is a column):

```
SELECT ABC ,                          --<---- comma added here
  (
  CASE 
    WHEN 
      condition
    THEN 1
    WHEN
      condition2
    THEN 2 
    ELSE 3
  END
  ) AS column_name 
FROM tablename;
```

You can also remove those parentheses, not needed really.

---

It's not clear why you added that `WHERE column_name <> 3`. Your adjusted `CASE` turned those `NULL` into `3`. Do you want to show those rows or not? If yes, keep the query as above. If not, you could use this:

```
SELECT 
  ABC , 
  CASE 
    WHEN 
      condition
    THEN 1
    WHEN
      condition2
    THEN 2 
    ELSE 3
  END AS column_name 
FROM tablename
WHERE (condition) OR (condition2) ;
```

or (that's closer to your logic):

```
SELECT *
FROM
  ( SELECT 
      ABC , 
      CASE 
        WHEN 
          condition
        THEN 1
        WHEN
          condition2
        THEN 2 
        ELSE 3
      END AS column_name 
    FROM tablename
  ) AS tmp
WHERE column_name <> 3 ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NVL(something, 0)` and if `something` would have generated a `NULL`, you'll get 0 instead.

Comment: I dont want the rows which do not have 1 or 2. Can I get only rows which have only 1 or 2.

Comment: That's what `WHERE` clauses are for.